# Configuring xUnit test output in Hudson

Tags: visual-studio-2008, hudson, xunit, unittest++

I have a simple PoC project in Hudson.  The PoC has unit tests written via UnitTest++ and outputs the results as XML for consumption by xUnit to munge into jUnit format.

Here are the salient relevant

- I have my project configured to use MSBuild to build the 2008 solution.
- The project contains both the dll it is to build and the unit tests which are run as a post-build step.
- I set my workspace in Hudson is set to c:\develop\money (Money is the name of the project) and in the Hudson console I can see the workspace folders, the solution file and output folders (/bin, /doc, etc).
- The test console app outputs its file 'money_unit_tests.xml' to the folder 'reports' (making c:\develop\money\reports) which is precreated.

However it seems that the workspace isn't sticking.  If I submit the workspace directory it shows me the folders but if I then reload the page then it shows the 'No files in directory' message.

**Why does Hudson not use C:\Develop... like I configured it?**

**What can I do change it?**

**If I can't change it, what can I do to mitigate these changes?**  (I don't exactly want to hardcode the output for the xml to C:.hudson...)

Comment: Is it a permissions issue? Did Hudson create C:\develop\money?

Comment: It was precreated.  It seems that the workspace isn't sticking.  I restarted hudson and the workspace is blank again. If I submit the workspace directory it shows me the folders but if I then reload the page then it shows the 'No files in directory' message.  I've updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears in Configure there is an Advanced option which hides several additional options.  Under there is custom workspace, which puzzles me as to what the workspace folder is for (which is still blank).

Comment: If you need your workspace at a specific location. That is where you configure it. --- What Do you actually mean with setting the workspace? Do you change the value of the WORKSPACE environment variable?

Comment: If you look in your project, there is a big folder called Workspace.
If you click on it you are presented with a text box and a green button which says Submit.  Set that to a directory name, submit it updates showing the files and folders in there but doesn't actually stick - if you reload the page it is the same if you hadn't visited there.